# Custom control in jwplayer

Tags: controls, jwplayer

Is this possible to add extra control in jwplayer? I can show you example where they are using on extra control for listening Episode [Customecontrol](http://blog.blogtalkradio.com/blogtalkradio/blogtalkradio-embeddable-player/)

Comment: We do not support adding custom buttons, only dock icons.